# Using reduce to get sum of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to have a sum of all the particulars which are in selectedIds array.

```
return [
      {
        id: 1244,
        name: "Installment 1",
        amount: 10000,
        due_date: new Date(),
        particulars: [
          {
            id: 2415123,
            name: "Development Fee",
            amount: 5000,
          },
          {
            id: 14123,
            name: "Library Fee",
            amount: 3000,
          },
          {
            id: 5123151,
            name: "Sports Fee",
            amount: 2000,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1412,
        name: "Installment 2",
        amount: 6000,
        due_date: new Date(),
        particulars: [
          {
            id: 414,
            name: "Development Fee",
            amount: 5000,
          },
          {
            id: 5123,
            name: "Library Fee",
            amount: 3000,
          },
          {
            id: 515151,
            name: "Sports Fee",
            amount: 2000,
          },
        ]
```

```
const selectedIds = [14123, 414];
```

In the object, I want to have a sum of all the particulars which are in selectedIds array.
I was trying to use array function to get the result. This is what I could come up with.

```
const selectedInstallments = this.studentInstallments
        .filter((installment) =>
          installment.particulars.some((particular) =>
            this.selectedParticulars.includes(particular.id)
          )
        )
        .map((installment) => installment.particulars);
      console.log(selectedInstallments);
      const sumParticularReducer = (acc, current) => {
        return acc;
      };
```

I couldn't figure out how to use reduce to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
const selectedIds = [14123, 414];
const sum = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    return prev + cur.particulars.reduce((old, item) => (
        selectedIds.indexOf(item.id) >= 0 ? old + item.amount : old
    ), 0);
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks... So in the inner reducer function, we are checking whether selectedIds match the item's id and if it's matches then we are adding the accumulator (old) otherwise we are just returning old?

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```js
const selectedIds = [14123, 414];

const idsArray = [{
    id: 1244,
    name: "Installment 1",
    amount: 10000,
    due_date: new Date(),
    particulars: [{
        id: 2415123,
        name: "Development Fee",
        amount: 5000,
      },
      {
        id: 14123,
        name: "Library Fee",
        amount: 3000,
      },
      {
        id: 5123151,
        name: "Sports Fee",
        amount: 2000,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1412,
    name: "Installment 2",
    amount: 6000,
    due_date: new Date(),
    particulars: [{
        id: 414,
        name: "Development Fee",
        amount: 5000,
      },
      {
        id: 5123,
        name: "Library Fee",
        amount: 3000,
      },
      {
        id: 515151,
        name: "Sports Fee",
        amount: 2000,
      },
    ]
  }
]

const sum = idsArray.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value.particulars.reduce(
    (partSum, partValue) => selectedIds.includes(partValue.id) ? (partSum + partValue.amount) : partSum, 0),
  0
);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1244,
    name: "Installment 1",
    amount: 10000,
    due_date: new Date(),
    particulars: [{
        id: 2415123,
        name: "Development Fee",
        amount: 5000,
      },
      {
        id: 14123,
        name: "Library Fee",
        amount: 3000,
      },
      {
        id: 5123151,
        name: "Sports Fee",
        amount: 2000,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1412,
    name: "Installment 2",
    amount: 6000,
    due_date: new Date(),
    particulars: [{
        id: 414,
        name: "Development Fee",
        amount: 5000,
      },
      {
        id: 5123,
        name: "Library Fee",
        amount: 3000,
      },
      {
        id: 515151,
        name: "Sports Fee",
        amount: 2000,
      },
    ]
  }
]
const selectedIds = [14123, 414];

const result = selectedIds.reduce(
  (acc, id) => acc + data.reduce(
    (acc, { particulars }) => 
      acc + (particulars.find(p => p.id === id)?.amount || 0)
     , 0)
   , 0)

console.log(result)
```